# How long should I wait for a job contract letter?

Tags: job-offer, new-hires

I recently had success with a big tech company in NY. I have accepted the offer over the phone after which received the details of salary-benefits, starting date and manager name - all basically the key parts of the contract in an email.

But I haven't received the contract yet and it has been 9 days since they said in an email that I will receive it shortly.

How should I ask them about it?

Comment: Who did you speak to on the phone? Have you a more direct means of contacting them?

Comment: I spoke to the recruiter who is in charge of my hiring process. I do have their direct contact number as well.

Comment: May be some administrative procedural delay, call and ask

Comment: Amazing how many of these *pick up the phone and call* questions we are seeing these days.

Answer (score 4):

9 days is long enough, give them a call and politely see if you can find out what is happening.

Comment: The key word in this statement is **call**, as in *phone call*.